# Android getting unchecked checkbox in checklist after search in edittext

Tags: android, checkbox

I have checklist with search functionality(used edittext). When I use it to search it shows filtered items so that I can make the selection that I want, it works properly. However, the checked items become unchecked when the search functionality reloads the list. I want the items selected before the search to remain selected. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
public class Lab extends Fragment {  
Button mViewBtn,msaveBtn;    
EditText mReviewdateEdt,mInputSearch;  
TextView mMostprecrdTxv,mViewmoreTxv;  
View android;
//   final Context context = getActivity();
MyCustomAdapter dataAdapter = null;
ListView listView;
DatabaseHandler db;
SQLiteDatabase db1;
Pharmacy mPharmacyFrag;  
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)   {

    android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lab_frag, container, false);

    db=new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());


    getIds();
    displayListView();
    viewAlertDialog();
    saveAlertdialog();

    return android;
}

private void getIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mViewBtn = (Button)android.findViewById(R.id.view);
    msaveBtn = (Button)android.findViewById(R.id.save);

    mInputSearch = (EditText)android.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    listView = (ListView)android.findViewById(R.id.list);

 }

ArrayList<States> stateList = new ArrayList<States>();
ArrayList<States> text_sort = new ArrayList<States>();



private void displayListView()
{


    stateList = new ArrayList<States>();

    States _states = new States("17 KETOSTERIODS","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);        

    _states = new States("17-ALPHA HYDROXY PROGESTERON","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("24 HRS URINE ALBUMIN","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("24HRS URINARYCORTISOL/CREATININE RATIO","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("24HRS URINE PROTEIN","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("2D ECHO","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("2D ECHO&DOPPLER STUDY","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("5-HYDROXY INDOLE ACETIC ACID","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("ABSOLUTE EOSINOPHIL COUNT","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);
    _states = new States("ABSOLUTE NEUTROPHILIC COUNT","",false);
    stateList.add(_states);

    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),R.layout.state_info, stateList);


    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);



    mInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
        {

            int textlength = mInputSearch.getText().length();
            text_sort.clear();

            for (int i = 0; i < stateList.size(); i++)
            {
                   System.out.println("firstlooop"+mInputSearch.getText().toString());
                System.out.println("names"+stateList.get(i).getCode());
                if (stateList.get(i).getCode().toLowerCase().contains(mInputSearch.getText().toString())||stateList.get(i).getCode().toUpperCase().contains(mInputSearch.getText().toString()))  

                {
                    States _states = new States(stateList.get(i).getCode(),"",false);
                    text_sort.add(_states);
                    System.out.println("Gdafdhujgkgj");

                }
            }

            System.out.println("text_sort"+text_sort.size());
            dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.state_info, text_sort);
            listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });



private class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<States>


{

    private LayoutInflater vi;
    private ArrayList<States> stateList;


    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,

                           ArrayList<States> stateList)
    {

        super(context, textViewResourceId, stateList);
        this.stateList = new ArrayList<States>();
        this.stateList.addAll(stateList);

  vi = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    private class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView code;
        CheckBox name;
    }

 @Override

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

    {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        Log.v("ConvertView", String.valueOf(position));

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.state_info, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.code = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);

            holder.name =(CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()

            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;

                    States _state = (States) cb.getTag();

                    _state.setSelected(cb.isChecked());



                }
            });

        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        States state = stateList.get(position);

        holder.code.setText( state.getCode());

        holder.name.setText(state.getName());

        holder.name.setChecked(state.isSelected());

        holder.name.setTag(state);

        return convertView;
    }

}



private void viewAlertDialog()
{


    mViewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



        @Override


        public void onClick(View arg0) {


 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());              

            StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();

            ArrayList<States> stateList = dataAdapter.stateList;

            for(int i=0;i<stateList.size();i++)
            {
                States state = stateList.get(i);

                if(state.isSelected())
                {
                    responseText.append("\n\n" + state.getCode());

                }
            }
 final TextView myView = new TextView(getActivity());

            myView.setText("Selected Tests are : \n"+responseText);

            myView.setTextSize(14);

            alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(myView);

            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

  alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Close",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)
                {

                }
            });



            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            alertDialog.show();

        }


    });
}

private void saveAlertdialog()
 {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    msaveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

          AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());


            alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Lab Orders Saved");
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);

    alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("PHARMACY",newDialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
{
                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                    int newFragmentNumber = 1;

   ((Tabswipe) getActivity()).setDisplayedFragment(newFragmentNumber);

                }
            });


            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();        
            alertDialog.show();
            StringBuffer responseText = new StringBuffer();
            ArrayList<States> stateList = dataAdapter.stateList;

            for(int i=0;i<stateList.size();i++)
            {
                States state = stateList.get(i);

                if(state.isSelected())
                {
                    responseText.append("\n" + state.getCode());

                }
            }

            db1=db.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values=new ContentValues();


            values.put("LabTests",String.valueOf(responseText));

            db1.insert("Labtests", null, values);
            Cursor cursor=db1.rawQuery("select * from Labtests", null);
            if(cursor!=null)
            {
                if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do

                    {

String tests=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LabTests"));

                    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
        }



    });

}

}






public class States {

 String code = null;
    String name = null;
    boolean selected = false;

    public States(String code, String name, boolean selected)
    {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.name = name;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public String getCode()
    {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code)
    {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected()
    {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected)
    {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

ListView recycles the views every time its associated edit text's value is changed. That's why the Check-boxes does not retain their states.

To accomplish your task:

Store the checked items in an array.
When you click any checkbox in the listview, change the value of that particular item in the array.
Inside your getView method, check or uncheck the Check-boxes by reading the values from the array.
That way your checkboxes will retain their states. I hope this is clear.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding . I tired to follow your instructions but I am failed to do I am new to android and had gone through many code pages but didn't get to complete this task.you can find my code as above please according to that provide code for me to analyse the logic because I am poor in logicsthanks in advance